# accented characters in MySQL field cause invalid multibyte string error in R

Tags: mysql, r

I'm pulling vertex attributes from a MySQL DB with CHARSET=latin1, and I get `Error in nchar(labels) : invalid multibyte string 326` when I try the following:

```
plot(graph,
 layout=fr_layout,
 vertex.label=V(graph)$univ,
 vertex.size=2,
 edge.arrow.size=.5)
```

For example, I have a vertex that is "Università degli Studi di Milano" and "St. John's University". What's causing the error, and how can I fix it? I've tried using `CAST` during my `SELECT` and replacing all punctuation, but that doesn't seem to change anything. How do I convert accented characters in a MySQL field to something R can use as a label in a plot?

Comment: Can you try converting the labels with `iconv`, e.g. something like `iconv(labels, "latin1", "UTF-8")` and see if it helps?

Comment: Thank you, Victor K.! This works: `plot(ischools_graph,
     layout=fr_layout,
     vertex.label=iconv(V(ischools_graph)$org, "latin1", "UTF-8"),
     vertex.size=2,
     edge.arrow.size=.5
)`

Comment: OK, I'll post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `iconv` to convert between latin-1 and UTF-8 encoding:

```
iconv(labels, "latin1", "UTF-8")
```